# Error when try to excute Apple Push Notification through php file

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on push notification in IOS with php server and I produced the certificate and keys of the app also I'm ensure from unblocking port for ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196 and 2195 but at all time I get this error during try to connect on ssl also  I'm sure from the permission of all key files

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL: crypto enabling timeout in /Users/samahahmaed/Desktop/CER/newspush.php on line 24

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /Users/samahahmaed/Desktop/CER/newspush.php on line 24

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /Users/samahahmaed/Desktop/CER/newspush.php on line 24
Failed to connect: 0
```

Edited:

When I'm trying this command

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert PushCertificate.pem -key PushKey.pem -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
```

I get this error

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=54
```

php file:

```
  <?php

  // Put your device token here (without spaces):
  $deviceToken = 'mydevicetokenhere';

 // Put your private key's passphrase here:
 $passphrase = '1234';

 $message = $argv[1];
 $url = $argv[2];

 if (!$message || !$url)
exit('Example Usage: $php newspush.php \'Breaking News!\'   \'https://raywenderlich.com\'' . "\n");



$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert',  'apple_push_notification_production.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
  $fp = stream_socket_client(
  'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
  $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

  if (!$fp)
  exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

  echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

  // Create the payload body
   $body['aps'] = array(
   'alert' => $message,
   'sound' => 'default',
   'link_url' => $url,
  );

  // Encode the payload as JSON
   $payload = json_encode($body);

 // Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

 // Send it to the server
 $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

 if (!$result)
  echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
 else
  echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

 // Close the connection to the server
  fclose($fp);
```

I searched a lot about this issue and I tried all possible solutions but without any result what I can do now ?

Edited:

After add -debug to openssl command the most strange thing these lines:
[image]

Comment: ????? :( I'm trying with this problem from 2 days without any result until now :((((

Comment: As @kerry suggested in their answer, this seems like a certificate problem. Try adding the `-debug` flag to your `openssl` command and updating your question with the results. That might provide additional information for troubleshooting your issue.

Comment: @Palpatim as I said to Kerry I tried the 2 cases about development and production certificate and the same result at all times , I updated my post as you suggested after add -debug to openssl command

Answer (score 0):

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert',  'apple_push_notification_production.pem');
```

This line looks like you are using production certificate to connect to sandbox APNS. Try using development certificate. You can get the same from apple developer dashboard.

Comment: I used two cases without any changes in the error , I forget this name of certificate here only